# How to focus a textbox in a custom dialog, so that the cursor blinks inside the box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually here i want to autofocus a textbox while I'am opening a custom dialog box. Here I used autofocus attribute for the input field. But for me it's not working. How to add autofocus for the textfield in a dialog box. Can anyone help me?

```html
<ul>
   <li title="Create New"><a data-open="modalCreateNew" class="align-middle"><img src="../views/images/home/create_new_normal.png" /><span>Create New</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="reveal" id="modalCreateNew" data-reveal data-close-on-click="false" data-close-on-esc="false" data-animation-in="slide-in-right" data-animation-out="slide-out-right">
   <div class="expanded row header">
      <div class="columns modalHeaderContent">
         <img src="
         <c:out value="views/images/home/create_new_icon.png"/>
         "><span>Create New</span>
      </div>
      <div data-close class="modalHeaderContent" style="padding-top: 8px;padding-right: 8px;" onClick="$('#diagramName').val('');document.getElementById('error-message').innerHTML = '';">
         <%-- <img src="<c:url value="/views/images/common/close_hover.png"/>"> --%>
         <button class="btn-close" data-action="close">x</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row modalBody columns" id="modal">
      <div class="collapse row modal-new-title">
         <div class="columns">Enter the diagram name</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row margin-zero new-file-row" style="margin-top: 0px;">
         <div class="error-msg-container small-12 medium-12 large-12">
            <label id="error-message"></label>
         </div>
         <div class="small-5 medium-4 large-3 columns text-right new-file-text align-self-middle hide-overflow">Diagram Name:</div>
         <div class="small-7 medium-8 large-9 columns new-file-control">
            <input  id="diagramName" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row margin-zero choose-diagram-row">
         <div class="small-5 medium-4 large-3 columns text-right choose-diagram-text align-self-middle hide-overflow">Choose Diagram:</div>
         <div class="small-7 medium-6 large-5 columns choose-diagram-control">
            <select id="diagramType">
               <option value="VSM">VSM</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row modalFooter align-middle align-center">
      <div class="small-5 medium-4 large-3 columns text-center" style="max-width: 20%; padding: 0px;">
         <c:url var="createDiagramURL" value="editor/diagram" />
         <!-- <input type="button" class="button margin-zero create-new-dialog-btn" value="Create" onclick="validateFileName($('#diagramName').val())" /> -->
         <input type="button" class="button margin-zero create-new-dialog-btn" value="Create" onclick="createDiagram('<c:out value="${createDiagramURL}"')">
      </div>
      <div class="small-5 medium-4 large-3 columns text-center" style="padding-left: 0px;">
         <input type="button" data-close class="button margin-zero create-new-dialog-btn" onClick="$('#diagramName').val(''); document.getElementById('error-message').innerHTML = '';" value="Cancel">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show script that opens your modal please

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: `trigger('blur')` maybe

Comment: i didn't wrote ant script to open dialog..by using data-open="modelcreateNew" iam opening the dailaog..pls check the code@teo van kot

Comment: for me when i click createNew my dialog will open.then my autofocus is not working.that is my error@santosh gore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you show the dialog using jquery inside that snippet add this line-

```
$('#diagramName').focus();
```

**Update:**

And as you are trying to do it in a dialog which is getting visible after few seconds, so you may need to do it, after getting it fully visible.
Try this one-

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#diagramName').focus();
}, 3000);
```

**New update from code from comment:**

Try like this-

```
createNew() {
    $('#modalCreateNew').draggable({
      revert: true,
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#diagramName').focus();
    }, 3000);
}
```

However it's the solution which you just need to execute each time after showing the dialog.

Comment: thanks for the answer,I tried this one but for me its not working

Comment: thanks so much its working..but first time its working fine..when i closed dialog box and again when i opened second time autofocus is not showing.

Comment: function createNew() {
     $('#modalCreateNew').draggable({
        revert: true,
     }); 
 }
    
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#diagramName').focus();
    }, 3000);      while you refresh the page and click on createNew on that time its working.then close and again open its not working